# I have a list from where i should take some elements based on certain condition

Tags: c#

The list is having certain items, from which I should select some items on a particular condition and display. i am having a originstation number and i should select the destinaion which should be after the originstation. The list can hold stations in both the direction. For example 1 to 10 and 10 to 1

```
 for (int i = 0; i < entries.Count; i++) {
     entries = elementIdVsName
                   .SkipWhile(x => x.Key < SharedData.OriginStationNumber)
                   .Select(x => x.Key)
                   .ToList();
 }
```

In this way I am able to select and display stations in only one direction. With the same function , how can i display the stations after the origin in the reverse direction

Comment: You can use the `Reverse` method.

Comment: Could you please eloborate. I should do that also in the same for loop.

Comment: I meant to say if i give skipwhile the key == originstation number , then it can display in both sides, but it is not working

Comment: The LINQ method `Reverse()` takes your IEnumerable and reverses its order. If, for example, you used it on `{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' }`, the resulting array would be `{ 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a' }`. All you need to do is slip it in your LINQ after `.Select(x => x.Key)`.